# Can std::map or std::set be used to replace a hand written binary tree

Tags: c++, compression, binary-tree, stdmap

When converting C code to C++, is there any way to leverage the fact that std::map and std::set are implemented a red/black tree?

I picked up an old copy of The Data Compression Book, and have been cleaning up and debugging the code. When I got to the LZSS algorithm (a variant of LZ-77), I was impressed both with how simple the concept is and also by the great gain in compression when compared to the statistical methods.

The most complicated aspect of the code is not actually the compression itself, but the fact that it keeps the window index of each string in a binary search tree for fast searching. I usually like to write in C++, but left my program in C because I can't realize any great gain in clarity, efficiency, or anything else. There doesn't seem to be much to do except to bundle the data structures and complicate access to them.

I thought things would be easier if I could leverage std::map or std::set. Am I "barking up the wrong tree"? I figured there might even be another way, but sometimes I'm not very imaginative.

My approach was to extract the comparison code from the insert method of the tree and use it as the comparison criterion for the std::set.

Comment: `std::map` seems like a superior replacement for a binary search tree to me. Binary search trees have poor worst-case behaviour

Comment: Possibly another way would be to use a hash map, `std::unordered_map`. But without knowing the details of the algorithm I'm not certain if it's suitable.